Leak from paving stones down into the cold room
The approach to my front porch is paved with interlock stones. When it rains heavily, even though there is a slight slope, rain water seeps between the stones and the side of the house, and then comes in the cold room just below. I presume from the joint between the foundation and the cold room ceiling slab (which is the porch).
The foundation does not leak. The cold room walls are dry. Water leaks from the joint between the cold room wall and its ceiling.
Can I put some sort of waterproofing sheet to prevent the water from moving down next to the foundation?

A few pictures will help us better understand the situation

Yes, you can. Did you have a more specific question?


Can I put some sort of waterproofing sheet

Yes.

to prevent the water from moving down next to the foundation?

Probably not.
When water goes into the ground, it goes down until it reaches something that does not allow water flow.  Then it fills up any air spaces in the dirt until it gets back up to the top of the ground.  It will then puddle or run off from the top.  If it finds a path to run off while it is still below ground, it will do that instead.  If that path can take less water than the rain is adding, the excess will continue to build up.
In general, trying to turn your house into a waterproof boat will not work.  Real boats have to be taken out of the water regularly to reapply the waterproofing, otherwise they start to leak.  As you have discovered, this tends to happen at joints.  It seems unlikely that you are planning to lift your house out of the ground annually to add more waterproofing in any of the spots that have worn away.  That's what you'd have to do to make the waterproofing approach work on its own.
If you add a new waterproofing sheet of material, you will have to caulk it to create new joints.  These joints will fail in a few years.  Then the waterproofing sheet will allow water in (around the edges) and hold it against your house until it finds a way into the house.
The general recommendation would be to add more drainage.  The easiest drainage is to build up the ground near the house so that water tends to flow away from the house before sinking into the ground.  If that's not practical (e.g. you have a driveway that is higher than the ground near the house), then the next thing to do is to add drainage around the house.  For example, a french drain.  A french drain goes underneath the surface of the ground and has a pipe that drains away from the house (perhaps after running alongside it for a while).
You should also check the drainage from the roof.  It needs to terminate in a place where the water will continue running away from the house.  A common problem is to leave it too close to the house, where it just seeps back to the house (possibly underground).  It's also possible that the gutters have become clogged or have sagged such that the water runs off somewhere other than the downspout.

even though there is a slight slope, rain water seeps between the stones and the side of the house

This sounds suspicious.  Why would the water only seep between the stones and the side of the house?  Why not away from the house and then seeping underground to the house?  If you have a slope that drops a foot down from the high point at the house, the water can still reach the house a foot below ground level.  If that's high enough to reach the joint between the foundation walls and the cold room ceiling, then that's a path that you have to prevent.
There isn't a distance from the house where it is safe to discharge water.  You want to discharge water below the house, more than away from the house.
You might find that people could give you more specific advice if you provided some pictures.  At least one showing how the ground slopes away from the house and where that slope ends.

Thanks for the detailed reply. I wish I could add apicture but I am not getting the option to. I realized there was another reason. The eavestrough above had debris stuck and during the rains, itwas dumping water on the porch, which was then flowing down the porch to the interlock path and then seeping near the foundation.

So I have cleared the eavestrough and also put a 6" wide waterproofing membrane right under the first row of the interlock bricks to take the porch overflow a little away from the foundation. However I do not expect water to be dumped on the porch any more as the drainage on the eavestrough has been cleared.
